# Spring beans, making them available to other classes? My components are null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have the following CountryISOService class :

```
package restServer.services;    

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import restServer.dto.commons.CountryWithISOCodes;    

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;    

@Component
public class CountryISOService {    

    // Declaring map.
    HashMap<String, String> countryNameMap = new HashMap<>();    

    public void setInitialValues(String jsonToMap) throws IOException {
        // Code ommitted because it doesn't actually help with my question, and I don't want to make you read forever!
    }    

    public String getAlpha2FromName(String countryName)
    {
        // Code ommitted because it doesn't actually help with my question, and I don't want to make you read forever!
    }
}
```

Then I have the following Spring Boot application...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"restServer"})
@EnableMongoRepositories("restServer.repos")
@PropertySource(value="classpath:config/testing.properties")
public class RestServer {    

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;    

    @Autowired
    CountryISOService countryIsoService;    

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(RestServer.class, args);
    }    

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException, ParseException, URISyntaxException {    

        // Just populating the countryISOService with some JSON - that class actually maps it to individual JSON
        // objects - but I ommitted the implementation of that in this question because it isn't important.
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        InputStream stream = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/json/countries.json").getInputStream();    

        BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();    

        String line;
        while ((line = streamReader.readLine()) != null) {
            responseStrBuilder.append(line);
        }    

        Debugger debugger = new Debugger();    

        // Try to use the instance of the CountryISOService class that resided in "debugger" - instead of the one in here, as a test.
        debugger.seeIfSomethingExists("Afghanistan");
    }    

    // Wasn't sure if the getters and setters are needed when using Annotation - kept them anyway, just in case.
    public void setCountryIsoService(CountryISOService countryIsoService) {
        this.countryIsoService = countryIsoService;
    }    

    public CountryISOService getCountryIsoService() {
        return countryIsoService;
    }
}
```

This is the debugger class :

```
// I have tried adding @Component here, it didn't help - but I don't think I want this class to be the bean anyway
// I just want it to access CountryISOService 
public class Debugger {    

    @Autowired
    CountryISOService countryIsoService;    

    public void seeIfSomethingExists(String country){    

        if(this.countryIsoService == null)
        {
            System.out.println("the service was null");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("the service was autowired correctly.");
        }    

    }    

    public void setCountryIsoService(CountryISOService countryIsoService) {
        this.countryIsoService = countryIsoService;
    }    

    public CountryISOService getCountryIsoService() {
        return countryIsoService;
    }
}
```

I can use countryIsoService in the RestServer - but I cannot use it in Debugger - as it is null - I know this from doing that null check and outputting the line to say it is null - if it wasn't it would output the other one.

I also do not use the spring beans xml now, because I switched to annotation, is this correct?

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: As you know that spring bean are Singleton by default, so in your configuration, it will just create one instance of CountryISOService, and then all other instances will just referencing it, and its same state will reflect everywhere

Comment: So so I have to do this code :     ApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"spring/spring-beans.xml"});

    this.countryIsoService = (CountryISOService)context.getBean("countryIsoService");

... In every class I want to use the object?

Comment: Hmm - but when I do that code everywhere, then I get nested exceptions etc... Spring is supposed to be for dependency injection - but if I have to have that line everywhere, I could easily just be creating instances, or passing them to constructors and having singletons, without using spring? right? I am now completely confused! haha.

Comment: Never, repeat, NEVER use `new *ApplicationContext` unless you are in a `main` method. Doing that basically means you are bootstrapping your application, so each time you do that you bootstrap your application. I you do it you need to do it once!. So how are you starting this application? Is it deployed? Do you have a class with a `main` ?

Comment: I am running it as a spring boot application... The app context snippet is in the init method when everything runs up. I just want to be able to use my beans in other classes... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using Spring boot application, then what's the need of XML Configuration, just use simple annotation like

@Autowired
CountryISOService countryIsoService;

Comment: Because I have absolutely 100% no idea where to begin with annotation - and as much as I would LOVE to know it, I really don't have time to learn from the beginning on this particular piece of work. I spent a whole day trying to make this work using annotations, and had to go back to XML because at least I can get that to package! I am more than willing to give the annotation method another try - by any chance could you adapt the code in my question to show me how I might get something like that to work? Sorry for being so demanding, I've just been banging my head off of this problem for days!

Comment: Ok, let me give you Spring boot version of this application, using just annotation, its too simple

Comment: Change the scope of your RestServer bean to prototype. Look at the docu https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s05.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are totally using Spring boot application. Then you can do it like

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestingApplication {

    @Autowired
    RestServer server;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestingApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public String value(@Autowired RestServer server){
        return "";
    }
}
```

and Other classes will look like so

```
@Component
public class CountryISOService {
  //anything you want
}
```

Bean injection can be done like

```
 @Service
    public class RestServer {

        @Autowired
        CountryISOService countryIsoService;

        //
    }

@Component
public class Debugger {

    @Autowired
    CountryISOService countryIsoService;
}
```

Comment: When I do this - I get a null pointer exception when I try to use the autowired object from the Debugger class.

I can create it in the RestServer class, autowiring works, I can call methods in it, etc. But then if I autowire CountryISOService inside of debugger, it doesn't work from there... I get a null pointer...

Comment: I edited my question in order to show you my new code based on your answer - What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, sorry for late replay, actually I was on leave.
Note:
1. There is no need of getters() and setters() if you are using @Autowire
2. In case of using Annotations, there is no need of XML Configuration

Comment: Try to @Autowire your objects instead of just initiating otherwise it will not work, like you done with your Debugger( Debugger debugger = new Debugger(); ), that's why your autowired objects inside Debugger are not working

Comment: If you are working with @Autowire, then you have to either declare your component as @Component/@Service or create its bean, otherwise it will not work